# SwiftUI - ReferenceFileDocument - Inability to indicate a document needs saving

Tags: swiftui

When creating a class conforming to `ReferenceFileDocument`, how do you indicate the document needs saving. i.e. the equivalent of the `NSDocument`'s `updateChangeCount` method?

Comment: My understanding is, that the App framework uses the published/observable objects to monitor and understand if an update happened. It then call's the snapshot to capture/save the document. The undo manager does not seem to be needed.  Xcode 14.2 (14C18)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've met the same problem that the SwiftUI `ReferenceFileDocument` cannot trigger the update. Recently, I've received feedback via the bug report and been suggested to register an undo.

Turns out the update of `ReferenceFileDocument` can be triggered, just like `UIDocument`, by registering an undo action. The difference is that the `DocumentGroup` <del>explicitly</del> **implicitly** setup the `UndoManager` via the environment.

For example,

```swift
@main
struct RefDocApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: {
            RefDocDocument()
        }) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.document)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager
    
    @ObservedObject var document: RefDocDocument

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: Binding(get: {
            document.text
        }, set: {
            document.text = $0
            undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: document, handler: {
                print($0, "undo")
            })
        }))
    }
}
```

I assume at this stage, the `FileDocument` is actually, on iOS side, a wrapper on top of the `UIDocument`, the `DocumentGroup` scene <del>explicitly</del> **implicitly** assign the undoManager to the environment. Therefore, the update mechanism is the same.

Comment: I'm confused - you say "DocumentGroup scene explicitly assign the undoManager to the environment" but where are you doing that?

Comment: @Grimxn Thanks for spotting it. I was meant "implicitly". The DocumentGroup implicitly assign the undoManager to the environment. On the contrary, ReferenceDocumentGroup doesn't assign the undoManager by default.

Comment: Ok - That makes sense! I’m finding ReferenceFileDocument just a wee bit obscure!

Comment: At least in my demo projects, as long as conflict resolution is required, I've to wrap the UIDocument/NSDocument myself anyway. Eventually, I've to wrote my own PsudoDocumentGroup. Have fun.

Answer (score 2):

`ReferenceFileDocument` exists for fine grained controll over the document. In comparison, a `FileDocument` has to obey value semantics which makes it very easy for SwiftUI to implement the undo / redo functionality as it only needs to make a copy before each mutation of the document.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/documentgroup/init(newdocument:editor:)-1mltk) of the related `DocumentGroup` initializers, the undo functionality is not provided automatically. The `DocumentGroup` will inject an instance of an `UndoManger` into the environment which we can make use of.

However an undo manager is not the only way to update the state of the document. Per this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ChangeTrackingUndo/ChangeTrackingUndo.html) `AppKit` and `UIKit` both have the `updateChangeCount` method on their native implementation of the `UI/NSDocument` object. We can reach this method by grabbing the shared document controller on macOS from within the view and finding our document. Unfortunately I don't have a simple solution for the iOS side. There is a private `SwiftUI.DocumentHostingController` type which holds a reference to our document, but that would require mirroring into the private type to obtain the reference to the native document, which isn't safe.

Here is a full example:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

// DOCUMENT EXAMPLE

extension UTType {
  static var exampleText: UTType {
    UTType(importedAs: "com.example.plain-text")
  }
}

final class MyDocument: ReferenceFileDocument {
  // We add `Published` for automatic SwiftUI updates as
  // `ReferenceFileDocument` refines `ObservableObject`.
  @Published
  var number: Int

  static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.exampleText] }

  init(number: Int = 42) {
    self.number = number
  }

  init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
    guard
      let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents,
      let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8),
      let number = Int(string)
    else {
      throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
    }
    self.number = number
  }

  func snapshot(contentType: UTType) throws -> String {
    "\(number)"
  }

  func fileWrapper(
    snapshot: String,
    configuration: WriteConfiguration
  ) throws -> FileWrapper {
    // For the sake of the example this force unwrapping is considered as safe.
    let data = snapshot.data(using: .utf8)!
    return FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: data)
  }
}

// APP EXAMPLE FOR MACOS

@main
struct MyApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    DocumentGroup.init(
      newDocument: {
        MyDocument()
      },
      editor: { file in
        ContentView(document: file.document)
          .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
      }
    )
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @Environment(\.undoManager)
  var _undoManager: UndoManager?

  @ObservedObject
  var document: MyDocument

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(String("\(document.number)"))

      Button("randomize") {
        if let undoManager = _undoManager {
          let currentNumber = document.number
          undoManager.registerUndo(withTarget: document) { document in
            document.number = currentNumber
          }
        }

        document.number = Int.random(in: 0 ... 100)
      }

      Button("randomize without undo") {
        document.number = Int.random(in: 0 ... 100)
        // Let the system know that we edited the document, which will
        // eventually trigger the auto saving process.
        // 
        // There is no simple way to mimic this on `iOS` or `iPadOS`.
        let controller = NSDocumentController.shared
        if let document = controller.currentDocument {
          // On `iOS / iPadOS` change the argument to `.done`.
          document.updateChangeCount(.changeDone)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunatelly SwiftUI (v2 at this moment) does not provide a native way to mimic the same functionality, but this workaround is still doable and fairly consice.

---

Here is a gist where I extended the example with a custom `DocumentReader` view and a `DocumentProxy` which can be extended for common document related operations for more convenience: https://gist.github.com/DevAndArtist/eb7e8aa5e7134610c20b1a7aca358604

Comment: One refinement suggestion is to ensure that the call to updateChangeCount(.changeDone) always happens on the Main thread.

Answer (score 1):

The `ReferenceFileDocument` is ObservableObject, so you can add any trackable or published property for that purpose. Here is a demo of possible approach.

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

class MyTextDocument: ReferenceFileDocument {
    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [UTType.plainText] }

    func snapshot(contentType: UTType) throws -> String {
        defer {
             self.modified = false
        }
        return self.storage
    }

    @Published var modified = false
    @Published var storage: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.modified = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand this solution would enable me to tell if any relevant property had been changed. However, what I'm looking for is a way to inform SwiftUI that the document needs saving.In the old NSDocument world, you could call `func updateChangeCount(_ change: NSDocument.ChangeType)`, if you weren't using the UndoManager. What is the SwiftUI alternative?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to access updateChangeCount directly with use of NSViewRepresentable. The only thing I'm trying to work out at the moment is how to remove the binding as it prevents the document class from deallocating once the window is closed.

```
struct NSWindowAccessor: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var window: NSWindow?
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.window = view.window
        }
        return view
    }
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var window: NSWindow?
    func setDocModified(){
        if window != nil {
            if(window!.windowController?.document != nil){
                window!.windowController!.document?.updateChangeCount(.changeDone)
            }
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button("document modified"){
            setDocModified()
        }
        EmptyView()
            .background(NSWindowAccessor(window: $window))
    }
}
```